# Number of real solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the equation

$\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor 2x\rfloor+\lfloor 4x\rfloor+\lfloor 8x\rfloor+\lfloor 16x\rfloor+\lfloor 32x\rfloor = 12345$

does not have any real solution.

($\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$).

**My Attempt**

Let $x=I+f$,where $I=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $f$ denotes the fractional part of $x$. Therefore, the equation reduces to

$63I+\lfloor 2f\rfloor+\lfloor 4f\rfloor+\lfloor 8f\rfloor+\lfloor 16f\rfloor+\lfloor 32f\rfloor = 12345 $

$I=195+\frac{20}{21}-\frac{\lfloor 2f\rfloor+\lfloor 4f\rfloor+\lfloor 8f\rfloor+\lfloor 16f\rfloor+\lfloor 32f\rfloor}{63}$

Not able to proceed from here onwards

Comment: Hint: you have $\lfloor 2f\rfloor+\lfloor 4f\rfloor+\lfloor 8f\rfloor+\lfloor 16f\rfloor+\lfloor 32f\rfloor = 60$

Comment: @MihirSinghal: I don't understand how that's true.

Comment: Note that $12345\mod{63} = 60$.

Comment: You had very much the right approach. But as is often the case in number-theoretic problems, introducing fractions complicates things. It is better to write your equation as $63I=(195)(63)+60-(\lfloor 2f\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor 32f\rfloor)$.

Comment: @Mihir Singhal.I follow your hint .Now,$\lfloor 2f\rfloor+\lfloor 4f\rfloor+\lfloor 8f\rfloor+\lfloor 16f\rfloor<30$.Thus $\lfloor 32f\rfloor \geq 31$.Therefore,$\frac{31}{32}\leq f<1$.Finally,for all $f\in\left[\frac{31}{32},1\right)$,we have$ \lfloor 2f\rfloor+\lfloor 4f\rfloor+\lfloor 8f\rfloor+\lfloor 16f\rfloor+\lfloor 32f\rfloor=57<60$. Hence, no solution.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: The function is increasing and increases at all multiples of $\frac{1}{32}$ and remains constant at other places. But we have $f(195+\frac{31}{32})=12342$ and $f(196)=12348$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lfloor z\rfloor\in(z-1,z]$ we must have $12345\leq 63x$ and $12351>63 x$, hence:
$$ x\in\left(196-\frac{1}{21},196+\frac{1}{21}\right]$$
but since $\frac{1}{21}<\frac{1}{16}$, over such interval the given function is greater than $196\cdot 63-3=12345.$